# How can we expand partial derivative for complex numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

[image]

How this equation $$\frac{\partial }{\partial x} + i\frac{\partial }{\partial y}$$ is
expanded in the image given above?

Comment: There is a misprint: the last line should start with $(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\ldots$, not $(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\ldots$

Comment: Thank you @TonyK but could you explain the right-hand side of the first line?

Comment: what book are you reading?

Comment: @mrsamy functions of a complex variable by Krishna series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the first line in the RHS is an application of the chain rule for multivariable functions + the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Namely, we can write $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial v},$$ and similarly for $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$. Combine this observation with the C-R equations, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @MushiMath